# How can I use MediaPlayerLauncher with a ScheduledAgent task in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I tried to use MediaPlayerLauncher's show method in a ScheduledTask, but the player never shows. Anybody knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

MediaPlayerLauncher and other members of the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace can't be invoked from a Background Agent. See MSDN for complete list of blacklisted APIs in background agents @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

> **Microsoft.Phone.Tasks**
>
> All APIs in this namespace are unsupported.

Instead of invoking a Launcher/Chooser, consider updating your app's live tile and/or showing ShellToast. Those are really the main two UI centric ways a background agent can talk to the user.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to kick off an alarm or media or launch another app when the tile is updated, is that possible ?